# listview.setOnItemSelectedListener does not work

Tags: java, android, listview, listener

I'm using a string arrayList and a string arrayAdapter to populate a listView, this is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llHoursD"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="1">                        

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDay"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivName"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="Fecha Seleccionada"
                    android:textColor="@color/category"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/category"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />    

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/separator" />    

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvReservationTime"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="163dp"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_weight="1.99">
            </ListView>       

            </LinearLayout>
```

This is the layout where the textview that is in the list is located

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemAva"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code in the fragment

```
listHourAvali = new ArrayList<>();
            adapterListHourAvali = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.detail_list_reservation,R.id.tvAvailiHours,listHourAvali);
            mLvReservationTime.setAdapter(adapterListHourAvali);

            mLvReservationTime.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Prueba",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```

The list is filled in another method, the problem is that pressing an item in the list does not go into `setOnItemSelectedListener`. What is the problem here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android custom listview, setOnItemSelectedListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630468/android-custom-listview-setonitemselectedlistener-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful, selecting something is a different action than clicking something.

see: [OnItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) vs [OnItemClickedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

If you want to do some action when a list item is clicked (!= selected) then you should use the onClickListener:

```
mLvReservationTime.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
        long arg3) 
  {
        // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Prueba", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
  }
});
```